# No support for executing select query in bulk

Tags: database, mule

Why there is no support for executing select query in mule with bulk mode whereas it is available for other operations.
Even though it is not there what is the most optimized way to execute multiple select query in one shot?

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of executing SELECT query in bulk mode? Is that for different purpose or the same purpose?

- Different: then use different flow to handle it. Keep the flow for a single/certain purpose.
- Same: then utilize JOIN clause.